# xmpp-sip gateway videocall using freeswitch

Tags: video, xmpp, sip, gateway

I am trying to make a gateway between SIP and XMPP domain. I have an environment with FreeSWITCH and OpenFire (FreeSWITCH is registered as a component in OF).

A video call between 2 SIP users work, but I can't establish one between SIP and XMPP client (which is connected to the OF).

Do you have any experience with XMPP-SIP gateways? What should I do to enable such a call?

Answer (score 1):

You should try and find out if the FreeSWITCH [mod-dingaling](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Dingaling) module and the XMPP server you are using support the same version of [Jingle](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html). That will be tricky because Jingle is still in Draft and implementations are likely to be idiosyncratic.

If you turn on FreeSWITCH verbose debugging you should get some kind of error message back about where the call is failing.

Comment: thank You for the answer. mod_dingaling uses libjingle (the Google implementation of Jingle) and Openfire uses the XMPP Standards Foundation version. The incompatibility of these imlementations causes this error? Do You have an idea for a solution?

Comment: I think there's only one Jingle standard which is maintained by the XMPP Standards Foundation. What I suspect the problem is is that mod_dingaling is using a version of Jingle that works with GTalk. GTalk is yet to properly support the Jingle standard and instead use their own custom XMPP extension which while close to Jingle is not. I wrote a few blog posts on it here's one http://bit.ly/gNSjZo. As for a solution break out your C++ code editor?? I whipped up a quick C# XMPP app to talk to GTalk within a couple of days it might help http://bit.ly/fm2lfl.